# How can I create a dataframe from data I scraped from a website?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, web-scraping, export-to-csv

I'm trying to scrape website from a job postings data, and the output looks like this:

> [{'job_title': 'Junior Data Scientist','company': '\n\n        BBC',
>   summary': "\n            We're now seeking a Junior Data Scientist to
>   come and work with our Marketing & Audiences team in London. The Data
>   Science team are responsible for designing...", 'link':
>   'www.jobsite.com',
>       'summary_text': "Job Introduction\nImagine if Netflix, The Huffington Post, ESPN, and Spotify were all rolled into one....etc

I want to create a dataframe, or a CSV, that looks like this:

[image: Expected Output]

right now, this is the loop I'm using:

```
for page in pages:
    source = requests.get('https://www.jobsite.co.uk/jobs?q=data+scientist&start='.format()).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

results = []
for jobs in soup.findAll(class_='result'):
    result = {
                'job_title': '',
                'company': '',
                'summary': '',
                'link': '',
                'summary_text': ''
            }
```

and after using the loop, I just print the results.

What would be a good way to get the output in a dataframe? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to define the number of pages and add that into your url (ensure you have a placeholder for the value which I don't think your code, nor the other answer have). I have done this via extending your url to include a page parameter in the querystring which incorporates a placeholder.

Is your selector of class `result` correct? You could certainly also use `for job in soup.select('.job'):`. You then need to define appropriate selectors to populate values. I think it easier to grab all the job links for each page then visit the page and extract the values from a json like string in the page. Add `Session` to re-use connection.

Explicit waits required to prevent being blocked

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import json
import pandas as pd
import time

headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36'}
results = []
links = []
pages = 3

with requests.Session() as s:
    for page in range(1, pages + 1):
        try:
            url = 'https://www.jobsite.co.uk/jobs?q=data+scientist&start=1&page={}'.format(page)
            source = s.get(url, headers = headers).text
            soup = bs(source, 'lxml') 
            links.append([link['href'] for link in soup.select('.job-title a')])
        except Exception as e:
            print(e, url )
        finally:
            time.sleep(2)

    final_list = [item for sublist in links for item in sublist]  

    for link in final_list:  
        source = s.get(link, headers = headers).text        
        soup = bs(source, 'lxml')
        data = soup.select_one('#jobPostingSchema').text #json like string containing all info
        item = json.loads(data)

        result = {
        'Title' : item['title'],
         'Company' : item['hiringOrganization']['name'],
         'Url' : link,
         'Summary' :bs(item['description'],'lxml').text
    }

        results.append(result)
        time.sleep(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = ['Title', 'Company', 'Url', 'Summary']) 
print(df)
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False )
```

---

**Sample of results:**

[image]

---

I can't imagine you want all pages but you could use something similar to:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import json
import pandas as pd
import time

headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36'}
results = []
links = []
pages = 0

def get_links(url, page):
    try:
        source = s.get(url, headers = headers).text
        soup = bs(source, 'lxml') 
        page_links = [link['href'] for link in soup.select('.job-title a')]
        if page == 1:
            global pages
            pages = int(soup.select_one('.page-title span').text.replace(',',''))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e, url )
    finally:
        time.sleep(1)
    return page_links

with requests.Session() as s:

    links.append(get_links('https://www.jobsite.co.uk/jobs?q=data+scientist&start=1&page=1',1))

    for page in range(2, pages + 1):
        url = 'https://www.jobsite.co.uk/jobs?q=data+scientist&start=1&page={}'.format(page)
        links.append(get_links(url, page))

    final_list = [item for sublist in links for item in sublist]  

    for link in final_list:  
        source = s.get(link, headers = headers).text        
        soup = bs(source, 'lxml')
        data = soup.select_one('#jobPostingSchema').text #json like string containing all info
        item = json.loads(data)

        result = {
        'Title' : item['title'],
         'Company' : item['hiringOrganization']['name'],
         'Url' : link,
         'Summary' :bs(item['description'],'lxml').text
    }

        results.append(result)
        time.sleep(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = ['Title', 'Company', 'Url', 'Summary']) 
print(df)
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False )
```

Comment: I tried your first answer, it worked really well. The class was incorrect earlier because I was parsing a different job site and wrote "jobsite.co.uk" as a placeholder, had no idea its an actual site. I did have a placeholder for the pages, I just missed that line of code in my post here. Can you explain what re-using a session is? I havent used session before.

Comment: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects   _So if you’re making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP connection will be reused, which can result in a significant performance increase_

Answer (score 4):

Look at the [pandas Dataframe API](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html). There are several ways you can initialize a dataframe

- list of dictionaries
- list of lists

You just need to append either a list or a dictionary to a global variable, and you should be good to go.

```
results = []
for page in pages:

      source = requests.get('https://www.jobsite.co.uk/jobs?q=data+scientist&start='.format()).text
      soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')


      for jobs in soup.findAll(class_='result'):
          result = {
                'job_title': '', # assuming this has value like you shared in the example in your question
                'company': '',
                'summary': '',
                'link': '',
                'summary_text': ''
            }
           results.append(result)
      # results is now a list of dictionaries
df= pandas.DataFrame(results)
```

One other suggestion, don't think about dumping this in a dataframe within the same program. Dump all your HTML files first into a folder, and then parse them again. This way if you need more information from the page which you hadn't considered before, or if a program terminates due to some parsing error or timeout, the work is not lost. Keep parsing separate from crawling logic.